# Permission dialog appears when device is locked

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

When I ask for runtime permissions in Android, the permission dialog appears. At this stage, if i lock the device and unlock my phone again the alert dialog appears on the lock screen. It wont go until i press accept or deny.
Is there anything we can avoid this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: I think your app may crashed  after asked permission. So the permission dialog showing in Lock screen.

Comment: can you share your permission requesting code here?

Comment: @TariqulIslam i tried but application didn't crashed .

Answer (score 2):

**Story**

Here is what I found after investigating this problem:

When the app calls [Activity.requestPermissions(String[], int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#requestPermissions(java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int)), the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) for this method.

```
public final void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode) {
    if (requestCode < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("requestCode should be >= 0");
    }
    if (mHasCurrentPermissionsRequest) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Can request only one set of permissions at a time");
        // Dispatch the callback with empty arrays which means a cancellation.
        onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, new String[0], new int[0]);
        return;
    }
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().buildRequestPermissionsIntent(permissions);
    startActivityForResult(REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_WHO_PREFIX, intent, requestCode, null);
    mHasCurrentPermissionsRequest = true;
}
```

As we can see, the system starts a new activity.

```
startActivityForResult(REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_WHO_PREFIX, intent, requestCode, null);
```

I traced to the source code and figured out that the activity is [GrantPermissionsActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/+/cd71d9a/src/com/android/packageinstaller/permission/ui/GrantPermissionsActivity.java). It is responsible for showing the permission dialogs and handle events like Allow/Deny/Don't ask again.

From that hint, I use the following adb command to see the activities info.

> adb shell dumpsys activity activities

Before calling `requestPermissions()`

```
Running activities (most recent first):
  TaskRecord{e04b922d0 #1441 A=com.example.myapplication U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
    Run #0: ActivityRecord{ca6ffc3 u0 com.example.myapplication/.MainActivity t1441}

mResumedActivity: ActivityRecord{ca6ffc3 u0 com.example.myapplication/.MainActivity t1441}
```

After calling `requestPermissions()`

```
Running activities (most recent first):
  TaskRecord{e04b922d0 #1441 A=com.example.myapplication U=0 StackId=1 sz=2}
    Run #1: ActivityRecord{bb1aed2 u0 com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity t1441}
    Run #0: ActivityRecord{ca6ffc3 u0 com.example.myapplication/.MainActivity t1441}

mResumedActivity: ActivityRecord{bb1aed2 u0 com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity t1441}
mLastPausedActivity: ActivityRecord{ca6ffc3 u0 com.example.myapplication/.MainActivity t1441}
```

**Solution**

I think here is the flow to resolve the problem:

- When the permission activity is showing, if the user press the Power Key, we will remember the action that the app finishes the permission activity, and we pop the permission activity from the Back Stack by combine `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`.
- After the user unlocks the phone, we check if the permission activity is finished before, then we will show the permission activity again (restore the last state when the user leaves the activity).

**Implementation**

Because the app cannot detect users press the Power Key with [Activity.onKeyDown(KeyEvent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent)) and [KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_POWER), so we will use [Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SCREEN_ON) and [Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) instead.

**Step 1.** *MyApplication.java*

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private boolean isScreenOn = false;

    private final BroadcastReceiver screenStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            isScreenOn = intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        registerReceiver(screenStateReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    public boolean isScreenOn() {
        return isScreenOn;
    }
}
```

**Step 2.** *activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="showMyLocation"
        android:text="Show My Location" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Step 3.** *MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // When the permission dialog is showing, if users press the Power Key
    // to lock the phone, then the onStop() of this activity will be called first,
    // then the system will send a broadcast with Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF action.
    // The duration between 2 events is under 1 seconds.
    private static final long TIMEOUT_MS = 1000;

    // When onNewIntent() is called, we use this extra key to distinct with another events
    // which might invoke this method.
    private static final String EXTRA_IS_PERMISSION_DIALOG_DISMISS_WHEN_SCREEN_OF =
            "EXTRA_IS_PERMISSION_DIALOG_DISMISS_WHEN_SCREEN_OF";

    // Your location request information.
    private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final String[] locationPermission = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
    private boolean isPermissionDialogShowing = false;

    private final Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    // Check whether permission activity is finished when screen off.
    boolean isPermissionActivityFinishedWhenScreenOff = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        if (data != null && data.containsKey(EXTRA_IS_PERMISSION_DIALOG_DISMISS_WHEN_SCREEN_OF)) {
            isPermissionActivityFinishedWhenScreenOff = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Show the permission dialog again if we dismiss it when screen off before.
        MyApplication myApplication = (MyApplication) getApplication();
        if (myApplication.isScreenOn() && isPermissionActivityFinishedWhenScreenOff) {
            isPermissionActivityFinishedWhenScreenOff = false;
            isPermissionDialogShowing = true;
            requestPermissions(locationPermission, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (!isPermissionActivityFinishedWhenScreenOff) {
            mainHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Because the permission activity is on the top of this activity,
                    // so we will use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP combine with
                    // Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP to finish the permission activity.
                    MyApplication myApplication = (MyApplication) getApplication();
                    if (!myApplication.isScreenOn() && isPermissionDialogShowing) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra(EXTRA_IS_PERMISSION_DIALOG_DISMISS_WHEN_SCREEN_OF, true);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
            }, TIMEOUT_MS);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        isPermissionDialogShowing = false;
    }

    // User click on this button to show my location on the map for example.
    // This method is just for testing.
    public void showMyLocation(View view) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(locationPermission[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            isPermissionDialogShowing = true;
            requestPermissions(locationPermission, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4.** *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time @son-truong, your findings are very interesting and useful!